# Generated Barcode Image not getting scanned through scanner in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have generated dynamic barcode image in asp.net web application but its not getting scanned/reading through barcode scanner.
Below is the code where i have generated barcode image.kindly find it out.
Need Your Suggestion and help,awaiting your response.

```
string barCode = LblSerialNo.Text;

System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barCode.Length * 11, 45))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
            {
                Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 8);
                PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
                graphics.DrawString(barCode, oFont, blackBrush, point);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
            }

            plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
        }
```

Comment: First of all, how do you scan the code? If on screen (not printed), verify if your scanner can actually scan images displayed on screen (not all can). Afterwards, check if your scanner is configured to scan the symbology (Code 39 I guess?)